# Apply Ajax.ActionLink to a DIV using values from Model

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

There are a few similar questions to this already, but they do not cover using values from the model to send as arguments to the controller.

[Make DIV containing AJAX ActionLink clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24314116/make-div-containing-ajax-actionlink-clickable)

[Div as Ajax.ActionLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307451/div-as-ajax-actionlink)

Consider the following code in a Razor view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="itemDisplay">
        <img src="~/Images/@item.DisplayImage" />
        @Ajax.ActionLink($"Item {item.Id}", "_ItemDisplay", new { id = item.Id }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "itemDisplay", LoadingElementId = "ajax-loader", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET" }, null)
    </div>
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to apply that `ActionLink` to the entire `DIV`.

The problem when applying any of the JavaScript solutions is that I run into a problem of being unable to use JavaScript variables within Razor code (since one is client-side and the other server-side).

e.g:

```
function updateItemDisplay(itemId) {
    $('#itemDisplay')
        .click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("_ItemDisplay", new { id = *cannot use a JS variable here!* })',
                type: "GET",
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#itemDisplay').html(result);
                }
            });
        });
};
```

So my question is, using `ASP.Net MVC`, how can I make an AJAX call from a DIV tag and pass the relevant ID to the controller?

Comment: Sort answer is no. `Ajax.ActionLink()` is a method that generates a `<a>` tag. But why would you want to use `Ajax.ActionLink()` (which is now effectively obsolete - its not being supported in by the team in asp.net-core-mvc) when you can use the `$.ajax()` methods which give you far more flexibility.

Comment: But its unclear what your wanting to do here - the code in the first snippet uses `Ajax.ActionLink()` to generate a url based on `item.Id` which is a server side value - there is no javascript variables used in that code. If you do want to use a javascript variable in the `$.ajax()` method, then its just `var url = '@Url.Action("_ItemDisplay")' + '/' + yourVariable;` (assuming your using the default routes), or `var url = '@Url.Action("_ItemDisplay")' + '?id=' + yourVariable;`

Comment: @Stephen Thanks, I did not consider using Url.Action in the manner you described. That solves my problem perfectly. If you want to type that into an answer I'll accept.

Comment: Question edited slightly in response to close flag.

Comment: Still not clear where your javascrpt variable is coming from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simply to build the URL by concatenating the variable to the string generated by `Url.Action`:

```
'@Url.Action("_ItemDisplay")' + '/' + myVar
```